# Embedding of weighted Sobolev spaces

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

I define the following wheighted Sobolev spaces
$$L^{2,s}(\mathbb{R}^3)=\bigg\lbrace u\bigg|\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|u(x)|^2(1+|x|^2)^s<\infty\bigg\rbrace$$
and
$$H^{2,s}(\mathbb{R}^3)=\bigg\lbrace u\bigg| D^\alpha u\in L^{2,s}(\mathbb{R}^3),|\alpha|\leq 2\bigg\rbrace$$
I know that the classical Sobolev space $H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is contained in $C(\mathbb{R}^3)$ because $2>\frac{3}{2}$. Can I extend this result to the above weighted Sobolev spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Continuity is a local property: functions which are in your $L^{2,s}$ are locally in $L^2$, so functions in $H^{2,s}$ are locally in the Sobolev space $H^2(\mathbb R^3)$, thus are continuous functions (even Hölder 1/2-$\epsilon$).

Comment: For negative s too?

Comment: Yes of course, because of the $(1+\vert x\vert^2)^s$, locally in $x$ comparable to 1.

Comment: So the limit $$\lim_{|x-y|\to 0}f(x)$$, with $y\in\mathbb{R}^3$, has sense for $f\in H^{2,s}$.